# hacer una consuta en php y usar la variable en un ajax

Tags: php, ajax, paginación, tabla-dinámica

Estimados estoy haciendo una pagina donde necesito una listado de resultados, una pagina php donde  tengo la solicitud de la variable principal que es cod_proyecto con un formulario, con esta variable debo realizar el filtrado de la base de datos, para esto uso ajax con el evento click del  button y uso con parametros de cantidad de registros (para usar un paginador), el ajax solicita a un php los datos segun el criterio. el mismo ajax crea la tabla con los datos. el problema es que tengo las variables de parametros estaticas, aun no he consegido como pasarlas, y para realizar el paginador  necesito realizar una consulta de los registros totales para determinar la cantidad de paginas, pero no logro como hacer el pase variables, me  disculpo si es un poco engorroso.

mainconsultarcc1.php

```
<div class="mainconten">
      <h4>Listado</h4>
      <div class="head_Consult">
        <form>
              <label for="cod_proyecto">Codigo del Proyecto:</label>
              <input type="text" name="cod_proyecto" id="cod_proyecto"> </input>
              <input type="button" name="btn1" id="btn1"  value="Buscar">
              <label for="lbl_total_reg" >Total de registros:</label>
              <input type="text" name="total_Reg" id="total_Reg" disabled ></input>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="tabla_Bloqueresultados">
          <table class="tabla_resultados">
            <thead id="Headlistadoconsulta"></thead>
            <tbody id="listadoconsulta"></tbody>
          </table>

          <?php
            include ('../conexion.php');

            $varobra= 2;
            $VarRegistrospagina=10;

            if (!empty($varobra)) {
              $result= mysqli_query($conexion, "Call BuscarResultadosCantProbetasRCC1('$varobra')");
              $Result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
              $Total_register = $Result_register[0];
              $paginasmostar = $Total_register / $VarRegistrospagina;
              $paginasmostar = ceil($paginasmostar);
              // echo $CodObra1;
              mysqli_close($conexion);
            }

          ?>


          <div class="paginador">
            <nav arial-label="pagina de navegacion" >
              <ul class="paginacion" id="NavPaginador">
                <!-- Ir al primero -->
                            <li class= "item-pagina">
                              <a class="page-link" href="mainconsultarcc1.php?pagina=<?php echo 1 ?>">
                                |<
                              </a>
                            </li>
                <!-- Ir al anterior -->
                            <li class= "item-pagina">
                              <a class="page-link" href="mainconsultarcc1.php?pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina']-1 ?>">
                                <<
                              </a>
                            </li>
                <!-- Ir cuerpo del paginador -->
                            <?php for($i=0;$i<$paginasmostar;$i++): ?>
                              <li class= "item-pagina <?php echo $_GET['pagina']==$i+1 ? 'active' : '' ?>">
                                <a class="page-link"
                                href="mainconsultarcc1.php?pagina=<?php echo $i+1 ?>">
                                <?php echo $i+1;?>
                                </a>
                              </li>
                            <?php endfor ?>
                <!-- Ir al siguiente -->
                            <li class= "item-pagina">
                              <a class="page-link" href="mainconsultarcc1.php?pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina']+1 ?>">
                                >>
                              </a>
                            </li>
                <!-- Ir al ultimo -->
                            <li class= "item-pagina">
                              <a class="page-link" href="mainconsultarcc1.php?pagina=<?php echo $paginasmostar ?>">
                                >|
                              </a>
                            </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

ConsultaRcc1.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btn1').on('click', function(){
      var valor = $('#cod_proyecto').val();
      // console.log(valor);
      var valorIni = 1; // estos valores sdeberian de venir de mainconsultarcc1
      var regporpagina = 20;
      if(valor !=""){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'tablaconsultaRCC1.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data:{consulta1: valor, valorIni: valorIni, regporpagina:regporpagina},
          success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
          let Resultconsulta1 = JSON.parse(response);
          // console.log(Resultconsulta1);
          let template = '';
          let templateHead ='';
          templateHead += `
                    <tr>
                        <th>Muesta Interna</th>
                        <th>Muestra Cliente</th>
                        <th>Diseño</th>
                        <th>Asent</th>
                        <th>Vaciado</th>
                        <th>Planta</th>
                        <th>Fecha Toma</th>
                        <th>Fecha Ensayo</th>
                        <th>Edad</th>
                        <th>Area</th>
                        <th>Carga</th>
                        <th>Rcc</th>
                        <th>%</th>
                    </tr>
                    `
          Resultconsulta1.forEach(Resultconsulta1 => {
              template += `
                    <tr>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.MuestraInterna}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.MuestraCliente}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.Diseno}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.Asent}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.Vaciado}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.Planta}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.FechaToma}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.FechaEnsayo}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.Edad}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.Area}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.Carga}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.Rcc}</td>
                        <td>${Resultconsulta1.Porcentaje}</td>
                    </tr>
                    `
          })

          $('#Headlistadoconsulta').html(templateHead);
          $('#listadoconsulta').html(template);
        }
        });
      }
    });
});
```

tablaconsultaRCC1.php

```
<?php

  require_once ('../conexion.php');

  $varobra= $_POST['consulta1'];
  $varIni= $_POST['valorIni'];
  $varFin= $_POST['regporpagina'];

  if (!empty($varobra)) {
    $result= mysqli_query($conexion, "Call BuscarResultadosProbetasRCC1('$varobra', '$varIni', '$varFin')");

    if (!$result) {
      die ("query fail:".mysqli.error($conexion));
    }

    $json = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $json[] = array(
        'MuestraInterna' => $row['MuestraInterna'],
        'MuestraCliente'=> $row['MuestraCliente'],
        'Diseno'=> $row['RccDiseno'],
        'Asent'=> ($row['Asentamiento']),
        'Vaciado'=> utf8_encode($row['Vaciado']),
        'Planta'=> utf8_encode($row['idtblPlanta']),
        'FechaToma'=>($row['FechaToma']),
        'FechaEnsayo'=> ($row['FechaEnsayoReal']),
        'Edad'=> ($row['EdadProg']),
        'Area'=> ($row['Area']),
        'Carga'=> ($row['Carga']),
        'Rcc'=> ($row['Rcc']),
        'Porcentaje'=> ($row['PorcentajeRcc'])
      );
    }

    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);

    echo $jsonstring;
    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);

  ?>
```